# MongoDB query over string field, returning revised string, using a function that is not built in

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to use a function that is not a MongoDB built-in operator, on a query? How?

example (aggregation query):

original query:

```
var aggQuery = [
            { $group : {
                '_id' : {
                    'configuration' : { $ifNull : ['$Configuration', 0] },
                    'logs' : { $addToSet : '$Log' }
                }
            }},
            { $project : {
                '_id' : 0,
                'conf' : '$_id.configuration',
                'logs' : '$_id.logs'
            }}
        ];
```

what I want:

```
function MyFunc(str) { return str.replace('A','B'); }
var aggQuery = [
            { $group : {
                '_id' : {
                    'configuration' : { $ifNull : ['$Configuration', 0] },
                    'logs' : { $addToSet : MyFunc('$Log') }
                }
            }},
            { $project : {
                '_id' : 0,
                'conf' : '$_id.configuration',
                'logs' : '$_id.logs'
            }}
        ];
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in this ?

Comment: No, MyFunc gets the string '$Log', not the value. (working with mongoose, Nodejs)